# JSP and MYSQL: how do I relay a SQL Exception

Tags: mysql, jsp, exception

I am trying to create a login screen which will allow a user to enter a unqiue ID. How do I relay the information to a user that the ID chosen is not unique. So far all I'm able to do is trigger the exception.

Registration.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Enter Your details here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Enter User ID</h3>
<br>
<form action = "RegistrationServlet" method = "post">
Enter User ID : <input type = "text"  name ="newUserId"/>
<br>Enter your Password : <input type = "password" name ="newUserPassword"/>
<br>Enter your First Name :<input type = "text" name = "newUserFirstName"/>
<br>Enter your Last Name : <input type = "text" name ="newUserLastName"/>
<br><input type = "submit"/>
<br>
<%=session.getAttribute("notUniqueUserID")%>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

RegististrationServlet

```
catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            boolean notUniqueUserID = true;
            request.getSession(notUniqueUserID);
            response.sendRedirect("registration.jsp");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution as it will reload the form and the user will need to enter all the data again, I would suggest you to use AJAX for this kind of verification.
Anyway here is a piece of code to set one attribute to the request and get it in the jsp.

Servlet:

```
}catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            boolean notUniqueUserID = true;
            request.setAttribute("notUniqueUserID", "Not Unique User ID");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("registration.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
```

JSP:

```
<%=request.getAttribute("notUniqueUserID")%>
```